# Perfomance issue with Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework

get performance issue with entity framework(vs6.0). 
In my website, get performance with one page (this page have long logic with database).

What is I have checked?

**Case**

That page is working fine with localhost. (Take time for page loading 7 to 8 seconds)

But it is working very slow with live. (Take time for page loading 1.30 to 2 minute). (Some time it is working fine with live and take time for page loading 11 to 15 second)

All other page working fine but there is not long logic with database.

If I compare all other page loading time with local and live then not got more difference.

Same data on database on live and local

Any one have idea Why it is working very slow some time?

Comment: some coder are making the mistake that they load too many data in their programm. e.g: If you have a database with ~1 million rows and 20 colums but you only need a few lines, then it is not good to make a "SELECT * FROM" (always load as much data as you need but not as much as there are!)

Comment: can you show your EF query ?

Comment: It is difficult. But There is many query with inner join. @database is small with data.  it is working fine on local but got issue with live

Comment: First time entity framework take time for create object. I think, It is take this time on every object (entity object) creating. Is it possible ?

Comment: without seeing it how can we give advice to you ?

Comment: Could be locking in live database (because of insert/update/delete) forcing  you select query to wait. This could be fixed with better indexes or loosening up isolation level on select if thats ok in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found issue of performance in my case. Not used Dispose() any object during process with Entity framework object.